# Why is a listview on Android (Java) stuttering when the other thread is busy?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, listview

I have a working listview in one thread that works quite good. But as soon as the other thread is busy, the listview starts to stutter really bad. The threads are not communciating or have anything to do with each other. If the second thread enters a prolonged sleep the list scrolls smooth again.

I have a dual core Tegra2 with Android 2.3.4 and don't really know whats going on. The device should be able to handle a simple list on 800x480 with ease if another thread is busy, but it doesn't.

Edit:

I kicked everything out of my list except alternating background colors and its basically empty now but still stutters way too much. What can I do in the list to improve its scrolling performance ?

Here is the code for the empty list

Any advice on what to do ?

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    LayoutInflater      inflater;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<String> processlist)
    {   super(context, textViewResourceId, processlist);
        inflater= getLayoutInflater();              
    }   

    @Override       
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {   
        if(convertView == null) 
        {   
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        }
        //
        if((position % 2) == 0)     { convertView.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000066);}
        else                        { convertView.setBackgroundColor(0);}
        //
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: That does indeed sound odd, especially on a 2-core box.  What happens if you setPriority of the non-GUI thread to below normal?  What is that non-GUI thread doing normally?

Comment: Show us your thread code, and did you play around with setting thread priorities?

Comment: Hi, reducing the thread priority did help a little but it still stutters way too much. The 2nd thread usually reads data and fills in a structure for the first thread to display but I complete seperated the 2 threads from each other to see if the transfer to the thread with the listview was causing the delay and it was not. It still stutters.

Comment: How about this: Get your thread running, then go to another app and try scrolling one of their lists. I suspect that you might not be reusing the views and optimizing the adapter enough.

Comment: How can I optimize it more ? I put the code for my list in my question and would appreciate any advice on this.

Comment: I think only Android 4 has proper multicore support. Android 2.3 only preliminar (for example theoretically all application threads are executed using same core, another application uses other core). Just google about.